# Invert Mouse Colour

Tags: mouse, windows-10

I recently switched from windows to ubuntu 19.10 and on windows there is a setting that allows the mouse colour to be inverted from the whatever the mouse is currently over.

For example, if the mouse was over a black screen, the mouse itself would be white. And if the mouse was over a white screen, the mouse itself would be black.

Another example, consider the third image from the left under the *Change pointer colour* in the  following link:
https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/img_5d1ba7fbd1afe.png

I am wondering if this is possible in ubuntu 19.10 and if it is, how would you do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this link

https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/bcanxa/mouse_cursor_inverted_color_scheme/ekupmfc/

looks like there was a patent issue and prevent people implement such cursor theme in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find color-inverted cursors for Ubuntu. However, my problem was to read text in tool tips that appear behind the mouse cursor.

This is how I switched to a **semi-transparent cursor** on Ubuntu 20.04:

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt install gnome-tweaks chameleon-cursor-theme`
3. Press the Super key <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> and run “Tweaks”
4. Under Appearance » Cursor, pick what you like, maybe “Whiteglass” or “Chameleon”.

[image: Gnome-Tweaks]